# Sending via MAPI in .NET 6 results in error code 2 / general mapi failure

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mapi

I try to generate mails in Outlook via the MAPI interface.

The code is built and tested in VS2022 against multiple platforms ("net4.6.1;net6.0-windows;").

The unit tests I have set up are successful for 4.6.1, but fail for .net 6.0 with an error code 2 ("General MAPI failure [2]") when triggering the static method "MAPISendMail" imported from MAPI32.dll.

What could be the cause? I cannot find further hints (checked the event log).